# Runtime Error : Session Graph is Empty. Add Operations to Graph

Tags: tensorflow2.0, keras-2

```
# Build a graph.
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

# Evaluate the tensor `c`.
print(sess.run(c))
```

This above code is taken from tensorflow core r2.0 documentation
But it gives the above error

Answer (score 0):

The thing is

The tensorflow core r2.0 have enabled eager execution by default so doesn't need to write tf.compat.v1.Session() and use .run() function
If we want to use tf.compat.v1.Session() then we need to do thi
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() in the starting of algorithm. Now we can use tf.compat.v1.Session() and .run() function.

Tensorflow core r2.0 have enabled eager execution by default. so, without changing it
we just have to change our code

```
# Launch the graph in a session.
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as ses:

 # Build a graph.
 a = tf.constant(5.0)
 b = tf.constant(6.0)
 c = a * b

 # Evaluate the tensor `c`.
 print(ses.run(c))
```

This gives the output without any errors
And one more thing to make eager execution enable in case then remember it has to be called in the startup of the algorithm
For more please go through documentation
If any issues please feel free to ask.
By the way i am just a beginner in tensorflow and keras.
Thank You !